# android Map view Issue

Tags: android, android-maps

I have made an application containing facility of viewing current location on map. I have used  default Map `Intent` to show map. It Works fine in Emulator but when I am testing in my Android device (motorola Millstone) , Map works fine but after view map, my application is not responding.anyone have any ideas why it happens?

```
String path = "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + lat + ","+ lon + "&daddr=" + b_latt + "," + b_lang;
String geoUriString = new String(path);
Uri geoUri = Uri.parse(geoUriString);
Intent mapCall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, geoUri);
startActivity(mapCall);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to show One Marker at Current Location,but In the code you shown you are passing two values to draw path..

To show user's Current Location on Map via intent you need to call this way

```
String uri = "geo:"+ latitude + "," + longitude;
startActivity(new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri)));
```

You can see **[More on This Site](http://www.androidsnippets.com/open-map-via-intent)**